# Laravel : save a docx as PDF

Tags: laravel-5, tcpdf, mpdf, file-conversion

I'm pretty new to laravel and I'm currently having some difficulties with documents. my problem as follows:

I have .docx document that I modify using \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor, after that I need to convert the resulted document to a pdf file in order to display it on my view.

I tried Mpdf but I noticed that it doesnt work with docx :

public function topdf($bill){

```
    $Mpdf = new Mpdf();
    $sourceFile = storage_path( $bill);
    $pageCount = $Mpdf->SetSourceFile($sourceFile);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= ($pageCount); $i++) {
        $Mpdf->AddPage();
        $import_page = $Mpdf->ImportPage($i);
        $Mpdf->UseTemplate($import_page);
        $Mpdf->WriteText(75, 73.3, 'hello');


    }
    $file_name = 'app/public/' . Str::random(18) . '.pdf';
    $Mpdf->Output(storage_path($file_name),Destination::DOWNLOAD);
```

}
If $bill is a file.docx this doesn't work, but if it's a file.pdf it imports it to another new pdf.

I'm stucking in this problem it's been a while. Any help please